# Eclipse text cursor has changed and editor behaves differently

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I pushed a magic button and now my cursor (the blinking thing that shows where you type) split itself and now Eclipse is acting like a plain text editor/like Microsoft Word. The cursor, which usually looks like "|", now looks like "¦" (what Wikipedia calls a '[broken bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Solid_vertical_bar_vs_broken_bar)' or a 'parted rule' rather than a normal '[vertical bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar)').

I just want to know how to get Eclipse to act normal again, and what I accidentally did so I don't do it again.

Comment: "the character above forward slash" is a question mark on _my_ keyboard... can you be more specific?

Comment: pretty sure the question mark is above the back slash. I thought that the direction of the slash is based on starting at the top and going to the bottom... If I'm mistaken then obviously I mean the backslash.

Comment: What does "fugoogin" mean? What does it mean when Eclipse acts like MS Word?

Comment: Fugoogin means it's frustrating me. I'm not trying to sound rude here but what do you mean what does "acts like ms word" mean? I mean the editing features of eclipse are gone except content assist. It doesn't auto insert brackets or indent or anything. Not sure what else that could mean beyond sarcasm.

Comment: That was a very well-posed question.

Comment: Funny how you describe it as "the character above backslash (a thin vertical bar with a gap in the middle.)" instead of just typing ¦

Comment: Not all keyboards have the same disposition of the characters. Try to be more specific.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

It sounds like you have accidentally switched from *Smart Insert* mode to *Insert* mode.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> or tick *Smart Insert Mode* on the Edit menu to switch back.

*Smart Insert* is the feature that automatically insert closing quotes and brackets when you type the opener and places semi-colons at the end of the line when you press semi-colon (if you have the preference for that enabled.)

Comment: Thank god, this split caret would have made me crazy!

Comment: @STM: It's funny how an apparently negligible cosmetic change to the cursor can drive us up the wall! Ctrl+Shift+Insert fixed it, though!

Comment: Took me a while to find this on google. I knew something was wrong.

Comment: Ahhh, brilliant. I don't even know how I turned it on (how the hell do you accidentally press Ctrl + Shift + Insert?), but you saved me!

Comment: I think it went from smart insert to normal insert when I changed the file extension to an unknown one, thanks, it was driving me insane! Also, it tells you which more you are in on the bottom bar :)

Comment: I thought something was wrong with my graphics driver - why does the 'smart' cursor look broken?

Comment: Still saving me seven years later.

Comment: You have to click on insert button not Ctr+Shift+insert

Comment: @AnandRaja Hi! Could you clarify your comment? I don't think there's a toolbar button for this. The solution is to toggle Smart Insert Mode on the Edit menu which has the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + Insert` on Windows and `Cmd + Shift + Insert` on Mac.

Comment: @mikej Hello, I don't know about mac. I've used in Linux. Insert button on the key board, when pressed first it'll change to insert mode and if again if you press, it'll chnage back to smart insert mode.

Comment: I've never been so happy to see a 10+ year old answer on here!

Answer (score 20):

Maybe you pressed the <kbd>insert</kbd> key, which will change the Eclipse editor to `Overwrite` rather than `Smart Insert` (see the info bar at the bottom of the editor), and will change the cursor to a block rather than a vertical line?

**Update**: Thanks for clarification - see *mikej*'s answer which is correct. I'll leave this answer in case anyone has the similar, related problem that I describe.

Comment: Incorrect, Insert would make it behave like Command prompt, not Microsoft word. Also insert makes the cursor a block and not a split cursor, as you said.

I have a vertical line with a gap in the middle of it, like the character above the forward slash...

Comment: @Jeremy it would help if you explained what you mean by "acting like Microsoft Word" then...and "split cursor"...

Answer (score 10):

Just double click on "Smart Insert" / "Overwrite" in eclipse status bar

For reference, I am adding image.

[image: Ecliple - Status Bar]

Comment: This merely does what the [`Insert`] key does, i.e. toggles Overwrite and whatever Insert mode is enabled. It does not toggle between Insert and Smart Insert modes, which is what the OP asks for.

Answer (score 4):

If nothing works, restart eclipse. That is what I did !

Answer (score 4):

Just click

> **Toggle Vrapper Icon** in *Toolbar*..

That may causes some issues like these. Because I'm also faced the same issue until today.

**Please refer the below images** to get clear idea about this.

[image: Toggle Vrapper Icon]

*Make sure that it is in **disable mode** in status bar*

[image: Status bar Confirmation]

Answer (score 2):

@Jeremy by saying " I have a vertical line with a gap in the middle of it, like the character above the forward slash " i guess you are referring to the ' Pipeline 'symbol, the one you use to denote' OR ' in programming languages. As people already answered, you are in Raw Insert Mode (as opposed to Smart Mode) so try Edit->Smart Insert Mode (Ctrl+Shift+Insert by default).
For more info you can visit this thread http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/53833/

And remember, the symbol is called 'Pipe' symbol or 'Pipeline' symbol.

Answer (score 2):

On my windows computer I press Shift + 0 but the zero has to be on the numeric keypad not the top row numbers.

Shift + 0 toggle my cursor.

Comment: This is the same as the <Insert> key but doesn't solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem, you can fix this by pressing just INSERT button on keyboard (on windows platform) also.

It worked for me.

or you can restart your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this symptom in Eclipse 3.7 before. And after I restarted machine, it disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If your cursor symbol is " **+** " then press *Alt+Shift+A*.
or else we can use Edit menu options ==> Toggle Block Selections

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring tool suite then you can double click on highlighted **Smart Insert** . Some keyboards do not have `insert` button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGkEB.png)